# JSF - Accessing a SessionScoped managed bean

Tags: session, jsf, session-variables

I'm quite new in JSF and I'm doing some basic things to get a feeling of how one should work with it. In my one of the projects I have a ManagedBean, SessionScoped like below

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable
// Having a couple of String properties (with setters and getters).
```

Now, in one page in a form I have a `<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{user.firstName}" ... />` which I would expect to get a value from the user and put it in my bean's property. The second page just displays the input data, accessing it from the bean. (`<h:outputText value="${user.firstName}"/>`).

The problem is that if after that I go in a third page (just by typing the URL) and I'm trying to use the same line to display once again the data from the bean, no data gets displayed. I was expecting that while the bean is session scoped it should still be available in the current session.

Comment: Are you opening a new browser ? A new browser means new session.

Comment: Not necessarily, MCA. Since IE8 and FF3 all windows/instances/tabs which are opened at once share the *same* session. Only opening a *different* browser make will create a new session.

Comment: Yes thats right some browsers share the cookies across new instances...

Comment: Everything happens on the same browser (FF3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you are using import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped, instead of javax.enterprise...;

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is still interested in this: I encountered the same behavior as described above. The solution was finally to replace @ManagedBean through @Named. Up to now I havent´t figured out the semantics of the @ManagedBean annotation. So I cannot explain what makes the difference.

Comment: Apparently you initially used the `@SessionScoped` annotation from the wrong package, exactly as answered by Daniel. If you use it from CDI's `javax.enterprise.context` package, then that won't work together with `@ManagedBean` which expects the one from `javax.faces.bean` package. You're here just proposing the opposite solution.